# R apply functional that keeps attributes

Tags: r, functional-programming

How can I keep the attributes (class etc.) of an object after applying a vector functional from R, such as `sapply` or `vapply`?

```
> d <- c(as.POSIXct(Sys.time()), as.POSIXct(Sys.time()) + 60)
> typeof(d)
[1] "double"
> class(d)
[1] "POSIXct" "POSIXt"

> sapply(d, function(x) x)
[1] 1510760756 1510760816
> vapply(d, function(x) x, double(1))
[1] 1510760756 1510760816
```

I could circumvent this problem with

```
> do.call(c, as.list(d))
[1] "2017-11-15 16:45:56 CET" "2017-11-15 16:46:56 CET"
```

but then I have to build a list first.

Thank you!

Comment: This puts them back rather than just keeping them but maybe it is sufficient: `"attributes<-"(sapply(d, identity), attributes(d))`

Comment: Thank you. Your solution is completely sufficient but still, I would like to find a clean solution where an `apply` keeps the attributes. Or know the reason why this is not included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sapply` has a default argument `simplify = TRUE` which forces the output to be a vector, matrix, or higher-dimensional array. If you change it to `FALSE`:

```
> sapply(d, function(x) x, simplify = FALSE)
[[1]]
[1] "2018-02-21 12:43:52 CET"

[[2]]
[1] "2018-02-21 12:44:52 CET"
```

you get a list.

Note that this would be the same result you would get from `lapply(d, function(x) x)`.

But if you don't want a list at the end, Grothendieck's comment seems the cleanest way to me. You can wrap it inside a higher-order function if you want it slightly cleaner:

```
> m.sapply <- function(x, ...) "attributes<-"(sapply(x, ...), attributes(x))

> m.sapply(d, function(x) x)
[1] "2018-02-21 12:43:52 CET" "2018-02-21 12:44:52 CET"
```